# DELETE query of duplicates wit OR Condition

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a problem with my delete query.

I want to delete all entries older than the newest timestamp, if the cn and the activity are identical.

```
DELETE FROM order_state a USING (
      SELECT MIN(ctid) as ctid, MAX(timestampms) as timestampms, cn, activity
        FROM order_state 
        GROUP BY cn, activity HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      ) b
      WHERE a.cn = b.cn 
      AND a.activity = b.activity
      AND a.timestampms <> b.timestampms
```

My only problem is that with the first query, all duplicates are deleted that have an older timestamp than the newest one.

If there are now entries where the timestamp is identical, both remain.

I actually need an OR condition in the DELETE statement.
Because if I execute the following query, my problem is solved.

```
DELETE FROM order_state a USING (
      SELECT MIN(ctid) as ctid, MAX(timestampms) as timestampms, cn, activity
        FROM order_state 
        GROUP BY cn, activity HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      ) b
      WHERE a.cn = b.cn 
      AND a.activity = b.activity
      AND a.timestampms = b.timestampms AND a.ctid <> b.ctid
```

However, if I try to combine the conditions with OR, then everything is deleted except for 1 entry.

```
DELETE FROM order_state a USING (
      SELECT MIN(ctid) as ctid, MAX(timestampms) as timestampms, cn, activity
        FROM order_state 
        GROUP BY cn, activity HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      ) b
      WHERE a.cn = b.cn 
      AND a.activity = b.activity
      AND (a.timestampms <> b.timestampms OR (a.timestampms = b.timestampms AND a.ctid <> b.ctid))
```

But why?

As you can see above, I am not able to get it working :(

Answer (score 0):

Hello there is a technique for deleting duplicated register using the cte WITH,makes the logic very easy and efficient for databases cleanup :

```
    with should_not_delete as (
SELECT * FROM (     
SELECT MIN(ctid) as ctid, cn, activity , rank() over( order by timestamps) as rank
            FROM order_state 
            GROUP BY cn, activity HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS a 
WHERE rank > 1 
    ) DELETE FROM order_state WHERE ctid NOT IN (SELECT ctid FROM should_not_
    delete);
```

Comment: Hi @mwalter, thank you. But unfortunately a older ctid can hold a newer timestamp. So i want to delete all entries which are older than the latest timestamp, grouped by cn and activty. But sometimes i habe

Comment: made a edit on the answer to fit better what you are looking for , the rank over inside of a subquery will allow you to search inside of the grouped values in order

Comment: Getting an error now, that the rank() over (order by timestampms) is not an aggretate function or in the group by.